# open a new url in a new tab using javascript setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, window, redirect

I'm trying to open a URL in a new tab after some time.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
      setTimeout("location.href = 'http://google.com/';",3000);
</script>
```

The above code opens the url in same tab.
But i want to open the url in new tab or new window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.open("/path/to/resource/")
}, 3000)
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/H7P2C59HE6tzhu4mlnlZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Does the "open" function help?

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        window.open("http://www.google.com")
    },1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is close , you'll just need to store your logic in a callback and **REMOVE .href**

Example .

```
setTimeout(function(){

window.location = 'http://google.com/';

},3000)

//FYI this will redirect page in the same tab vs .open() opens a new tab...
```

hope this helps

Comment: this opens in the same tab